# TAB (Horizontal Tab) in JSON

Tags: java, json, utf-8

I have the following string:

```
[{
    "data": {
        "title": "title=    10/100BASE-T 24/2"
    },
    "attr": {
        "id": "55555"
    },
    "state": "on"
}]
```

after `title=` follow TAB (`\t` or `\u0009`)
how i can save TAB in string and get JSON without error

[error from JSON viewer plugin Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWLSU.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution, that helped me just replaced all `\t (\u0009)` with `\\t`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't exactly understand what you mean. Assuming that the problem is only for JSON parsing, seems it would work: &#9; or html code &Tab;

Comment: I can not replace TAB with &#9 because it is not utf-8 format
I just need to save TAB at this String and this string should be able parsed like JSON

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a correct JSON string should not contain any special character: all non ASCII characters are supposed to be encoded. Here a correct JSON representation could be:

```
...
"data": {
        "title": "title=\t10/100BASE-T 24/2"
    },
    ...
```

because `\t` is a valid representation for a tab. It could also be `title=\u000910...`, because `\u0009` is a valid representation too.

**Any** unicode character can be represented in JSON **but** it must be encoded.

Comment: I have found solution, that helped me
just replaced all `\t` with `\\t`

Comment: @IvanT: yes, a `\ ` must be quoted if you want to keep it in a string...

Comment: I can replace TAB in string with followed code
`data.replace("\t", " ")`, so \t at front of title dosen't helped

Comment: yeah, i want to keep it in a string